# Could someone explain this bit of XML code please?

Tags: android, xml

For android development, we need XML and I have a couple of doubts about the syntax.

Here's sample code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/vMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On line 8, there is a `>`, could someone explain the significance of that? If I remove it, the editor complains because it seems to be invalid syntax.

Also, on line 12, if I replace the `/>` with the full closing tage of `</RelativeLayout>`, it will not work. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: 8 is the closing angle bracket on the Relative Layout node, which contains some attributes. 12 is the close to a single node <someOneTagInsteadOfTwo/> and the node has some attributes there too

Comment: @BenKnoble What is the difference between the 9 and 12 pair versus the 13 and 28 pair?

Comment: There is a child node, so the parent (13-17) cant be one tag; it needs two so that a child can come in between. However, the child (19-27ish) has no children and is a single tag. Then, on 28, you close the parent. And then close its parent at 30

Comment: Okay thanks! I had to do a quick crash course on the 2 different types of closing tags to fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

The '>' on line 8 closes the first `<RelativeLayout` node. '/>' is short hand for closing a node that has no children. The last `</RelativeLayout>` tag closes that first one. You can't replace it with '/>' because it has child nodes in it.